# How to call two method one after another?

Tags: android, json

I'm building a simple Android Application. I want to parse JSON. I have everything working using Button. But I want call it without using Button. It need to be get the JSON first from url and then Parse it. I have function getJson() and parseJSON(). First I want getJSON to be called and after 5 second parseJSON(). here is my code:

```
Runnable[] methods = new Runnable[]{
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(SheduleActivity.this, "This is gettin JSON", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    getJSON();

                }
            },
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(SheduleActivity.this, "This is Parsing JSON", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    parseJSON();


                }
            }

    };

    for(Runnable r : methods)
        //r.run();
       service.submit(r);
   service.shutdown();
    while (!service.isTerminated()) {}
    Toast.makeText(SheduleActivity.this,"Finished all threads", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Everytime I run my app only getJSON() method calls and stops. Any suggetions?

Comment: Put the log here please

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use AsyncTask. put getJson() in doInBackground block and parseJSON() on onPostExecute block. hope this help.

Answer (score -1):

Android does not suggest to use `sleep(5000)` for delay. Use handler to do this. See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) of Handler.

For example in your code,

```
Handler handler = new Handler( /* --- */ );
handler.postDelayed(methods[i], 5000);
```

Also for getting json from web, it is suggested to use `Asynctask` to make the UI responsive. Best tutorial for Asynctask is [here](https://www.journaldev.com/9708/android-asynctask-example-tutorial).